# Css priority navbar (menu) issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a simple responsive menu, there is a functionality to collapse menu content instead of transfer to down-word check on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ho79fhe/).

The problem I am facing that when I resize the browser and menu start hiding the button name `More` also hiding with resizing browser, I want that when menu start hiding it will never hide.

**HTML**

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="navControl">
        <a href="#">Navigation</a>
    </div>
    <ul style=" height: 50px !important;">
        <li><a href="#" class="active">صفہ اول</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">تازہ ترین</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">پاکستان</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">دنیا</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">کھیل</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">فن و ثقافت</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ماحولیات</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">کالم/بلاگ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">فیچرز</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ادب</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">اسلامی صفحہ</a></li> 
        <li><a href="#">تصاویر</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ویڈیوز</a></li>       
        <li><a href="">ریڈیو</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.nav {
    background: #333;
    direction:rtl;
}

.nav .navControl {
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px !important;
    padding-right: 0px !important;
}

.nav li {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2000;
}

.nav a {
    padding: 10px 10px;
    display: block;

    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: #ccc;
}

.nav span {
    display: none;
}

.nav .dropdown {
    text-align: center;
}

.nav .dropdown li {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.nav .dropdown a {
    padding: 0;
    border-right: 0;

    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.nav .dropdown li:last-child a {
    margin-right: 0;
}

.nav .dropdown ul {
    display: none;
}





/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*\
    MEDIA QUERIES
\*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
    .nav li {
        margin-right: -4px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .nav a {
       border-right: 1px solid #555;
    }

    .nav .dropdown {
        display: none;

        background: #333;

        position: absolute;
        top: 100%;
        left: 0;
    }

    .nav .dropdown li {
        display: block;
    }

    .nav .dropdown a {
        padding: 10px;
        margin-right: 0;

        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align: left;
    }

    .nav span {
        display: inline;

        position: relative;
        left: 5px;
    }

    .nav a:hover + .dropdown,
    .nav .dropdown:hover {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

**JS**

```
ResponsiveNav = function(nav, breakPoint) 
{   
    //if no nav container, output an error
    if(typeof nav === "undefined")
    {  
        console.log("The nav container needs setting.");
        return false;
    }

    //elements
    var navControl = nav.find(".navControl").first();
    var mainUL = nav.find("ul").first();
    var mainLIs = mainUL.children();
    var extraLI = $("<li class='extraDropdown'><a href='#'>More</a>");
    var extraDropdown = $("<ul class='dropdown'></ul>");    
    extraLI.append(extraDropdown);

    //variables
    var breakPoint = (typeof breakPoint != "number") ? 500 : breakPoint;
    var siteWidth = $(document).width();
    var lastSiteWidth = null;
    var navWidth = mainUL.width();
    var usingExtraDropdown = false;

    //listener for screen width
    $(window).resize(function() {
        siteWidth = $(document).width();
        navWidth = mainUL.width();
        checkNavType();
        lastSiteWidth = siteWidth;
    });

    //toggle nav when nav control is clicked
    navControl.on('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        toggleNav();
    });

    //check if to use mobile nav or not
    checkNavType();

    //added a extra dropdown if not already there
    function addExtraDropdown()
    {
        if (!usingExtraDropdown) {
            usingExtraDropdown = true;
            mainUL.append(extraLI);
        }
    }

    //make sure the LIs fit into the nav
    function checkLIsFit()
    {
        var widthLIs = 0;

        mainLIs = mainUL.children();

        mainLIs.each(function() {
            widthLIs += $(this).outerWidth(true);
        });

        //need a dropdown
        if(widthLIs > navWidth) {
            addExtraDropdown();
            moveLI();
        }
    }

    //move LIs to the extra dropdown from main nav
    function moveLI()
    {
        mainLIs = mainUL.children().not(".extraDropdown");

        extraDropdown.prepend(mainLIs.last());

        checkLIsFit();
    }

    //move all LIs from extra dropdown back to the nav
    function resetExtraDropdown()
    {
        usingExtraDropdown = false;

        var LIsToMove = extraDropdown.children();

        mainUL.find(".extraDropdown").remove();

        mainUL.append(LIsToMove);
    }

    //check if to use mobile nav or not
    function checkNavType()
    {
        if(siteWidth != lastSiteWidth)
        {
            if(siteWidth >= breakPoint)
            {
                navControl.hide();
                mainUL.show();
            }
            else {
                navControl.show();
                mainUL.hide();
            }

            resetExtraDropdown();
            checkLIsFit();
        }
    }

    //open or close nav
    function toggleNav()
    {   
        mainUL.slideToggle();
    }
};

$(function() 
        {
            $(".nav").each(function()
            {
                new ResponsiveNav($(this), 600);
            });
        });
```

Comment: nothing is `Urgent` here ... if anything putting something like that in the question will make people ignore a question

Comment: **Note:** it works fine in microsofts edge browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not taking into account the width of your `li.extraDropdown`(More) when you calculate `widthLIs`, it is not hiding, is going to the below line because it does not fit.

So to fix it just star it with 40 or with another value that you want (and that works of course) like this:

```
function checkLIsFit()
{
    var widthLIs = 40; /*here*/

    mainLIs = mainUL.children();

    mainLIs.each(function() {
        widthLIs += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });

    //need a dropdown
    if(widthLIs > navWidth) {
        addExtraDropdown();
        moveLI();
    }
}
```

[Here a working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/1ho79fhe/1/)